# Office installation won't open files downloaded from a browser

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

When I open an office file (I've tested Word / Excel) that I downloaded from a browser (chrome, ff, Edge), regardless of the source (gmail, dropbox web download) I get the following error:

[image]

This is on a box with:

- Windows 10 (genuine license)
- Office 360, installed locally - not the online version. (also licensed)

If I take the same word file, open it in another computer and then re-save it in a shared dropbox file, I can open it from the problematic computer no problem. It seems that it only happens when the file is downloaded from a browser on the same computer.

Is there some protection mechanism that I'm unaware of?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2749199

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the Word file that you have problems with, and select "Properties"

When the properties window opens go to the General Tab Click "Unblock" then "OK"

It should work now.

[image]

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2749199)

Comment: Where you been Mr.?  Come by the MVMR chatroom once in awhile.  Hope all is well.

Comment: Been busy, no time for free work, link to chat please.

Comment: It's Ducatikiller.   My name is Citizen here.

Comment: Ah, forgot, see you over there.